# Invalid conversion from int to typedef enum data

Tags: c++, enums, int, typedef

I have an old C++ code and I have a function which is:

```
void InitPlace( PLACE_NUMBER place, char* szName,
                PLACE_NUMBER pnNumSize, PlacePolicy policy );
```

When I call this function using:

```
InitPlace( 0, "", 2, 0 );
```

I get an error which says that:

> invalid conversion from int to PlacePolicy

placepolicy is defined below:

```
typedef enum {
    RANDOM=0,
    FIFO=1,
    LIFO=2
} PlacePolicy;
```

Do you guys have any idea why I get error?

Comment: Try casting `InitPlace(PLACE_NUMBER(0), "", PLACE_NUMBER(0), PlacePolicy(0));`

Comment: What is the relation between the types `PLACE_NUMBER` and `PlacePolicy`? Maybe you should just pass `RANDOM` instead of `0`? Or maybe you should create constants like `PLACE_NUMBER const RANDOM(0);` instead of the enumeration? BTW: It is common to use ALL_UPPERCASE only for macros, see any good C++ FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicity convert/cast `int` to `enum` type:

```
InitPlace( 0, "", 2, PlacePolicy(0) );
```

this assumes that you are positive that value are correct.
But you should probably do:

```
InitPlace( 0, "", 2, RADNOM );
```

instead.

Also, `szName` parameter is non-const char point and you are passing string literal.  make that `const char* szName` .

Answer (score 0):

Your function call should look like

```
 InitPlace(PLACE_NUMBER(0), "", PLACE_NUMBER(0), RANDOM);
```

I can't tell certainly since you don't tell us what `PLACE_NUMBER` type actually should be.

Also you can omit the `typedef` from the `enum` declaration, that's redundant in c++. For the actual c++ standard it should be

```
enum class PlacePolicy {
    RANDOM=0,
    FIFO=1,
    LIFO=2
};
```

and

```
InitPlace(PLACE_NUMBER(0), "", PLACE_NUMBER(0), PlacePolicy::RANDOM);
```